# Parse XML from String using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I'm pulling XML from a URL, which is behind a login screen.  I can enter my credentials and grab the XML just fine, but I'm having trouble parsing this string.  I think it's a list of XML tags.  Anyway, the XML looks like this:

```
<Report Type="SLA Report" SiteName="Get Dataset Metadata" SLA_Name="Get Dataset Metadata" SLA_Description="Get Dataset Metadata" From="2018-11-27 00:00" Thru="2018-11-27 23:59" obj_device="4500" locations="69,31,"><Objective Type="Availability"><Goal>99.93</Goal><Actual>100.00</Actual><Compliant>Yes</Compliant><Errors>0</Errors><Checks>2878</Checks></Objective><Objective Type="Uptime"><Goal/><Actual/><Compliant/><Errors>0</Errors><Checks>0</Checks></Objective><Objective Type="Response Time"><Goal>300.00</Goal><Actual>1.7482</Actual><Compliant>Yes</Compliant><Errors>0</Errors><Checks>2878</Checks></Objective><MonitoringPeriods><Monitor><Exclude>No</Exclude><DayFrom>Sunday</DayFrom><TimeFrom>00:00</TimeFrom><DayThru>Sunday</DayThru><TimeThru>23:59</TimeThru></Monitor><Monitor><Exclude>No</Exclude><DayFrom>Monday</DayFrom><TimeFrom>00:00</TimeFrom><DayThru>Monday</DayThru><TimeThru>23:59</TimeThru></Monitor>
```

I want to get everything between the  tags and everything between the  tags.  I want to load this into a Data Frame.  That's it.  How can I do that?

I thought I could use tree and root, like this:

```
REQUEST_URL = 'https://URL'
response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=(login, password))
xml_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore') 
tree = ET.parse(xml_data)
root = tree.getroot()
```

But that just gives me `NameError: name 'tree' is not defined` & `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`.  I'm hoping there is a one-liner or two-liner, to get everything tidied up.  So far, I haven't come across anything useful.

```
print(response.text) gives me:

<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?><Report Type='SLA Report'
 SiteName='Execute Query'
 SLA_Name='Execute Query'
 SLA_Description='Execute Query'
 From='2018-11-27 00:00'
 Thru='2018-11-27 23:59' 
 obj_device='4500'
 locations='69,31,'
>
<Objective Type='Availability'>
<Goal>99.93</Goal>
<Actual>99.93</Actual>
<Compliant>Yes</Compliant>
<Errors>2</Errors>
<Checks>2878</Checks>
</Objective>
<Objective Type='Uptime'>
<Goal></Goal>
<Actual></Actual>
<Compliant></Compliant>
<Errors>0</Errors>
<Checks>0</Checks>
</Objective>
<Objective Type='Response Time'>
<Goal>300.00</Goal>
<Actual>3.1164</Actual>
<Compliant>Yes</Compliant>
<Errors>0</Errors>
<Checks>2878</Checks>
</Objective>
<MonitoringPeriods>
<Monitor>
<Exclude>No</Exclude><DayFrom>Sunday</DayFrom><TimeFrom>00:00</TimeFrom><DayThru>Sunday</DayThru><TimeThru>23:59</TimeThru>
</Monitor>
```

Comment: Are you sure? This code should not cause these errors.

Comment: I know that the `xmltodict` library can load an XML string into a `dict` fairly easily, then you could use `DataFrame.from_dict` to load it into a Data Frame.

Comment: what does `print(response.text)` show?

Comment: I just updated my original post with print(response.text).

Comment: @ryguy72 FWIW, the first xml doc  you posted and the result of `print res.text` are not equivalent

Comment: I think it's the way the print(response.text)  works.  It's the same, except that the print(response.text) is a lot easier to read.